# Combining Maybe, IO and functions outside context result in error

Tags: haskell, exception

Can't figure out how to make code below work. Tried all possible typesigs I think.

Code

```
type SerialNumber = (String, Int)
serialList :: Map.Map String SerialNumber
serialList = Map.fromList [("belt drive",("BD",0001))
                          ,("chain drive",("CD",0002))
                          ,("drive pulley",("DP",0003))
                          ,("drive sprocket",("DS",0004))
                          ]
findSerial :: Ord k => k -> Map.Map k a -> Maybe a
findSerial input = Map.lookup input
outOfContext (Just (a, b)) = (a, b)
getSerialFromUser :: IO ()
getSerialFromUser = do
                    putStr "Lookup part: "
                    input <- getLine
                    let output = findSerial input serialList
                    putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output
```

Error

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[()]’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe SerialNumber’
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘output’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output
      In the expression:
        do putStr "Lookup part: "
           input <- getLine
           let output = findSerial input serialList
           putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output
   |
62 |                     putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output
```

Trying my first steps in Haskell without the books so please be gentle.

Comment: `putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output` means `(putStrLn "\nFound entry: ") ++ output`. Use instead `putStrLn ("\nFound entry: " ++ output)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Haskell function application is left associative, which means the expression:

```
putStrLn "\nFound entry: " ++ output
```

is parsed as

```
(putStrLn "\nFound entry: ") ++ output
```

But you probably expected it to be parsed as:

```
putStrLn ("\nFound entry: " ++ output)
```

That's why you need either to specify the parentheses explicitly or use `$` operator:

```
putStrLn $ "\nFound entry: " ++ output
```

But notice, that `output` is of `SerialNumber` type, but `(++)` takes two lists as an argument. Therefore, you need to revise, which behaviour you want to specify to your program.

Comment: also, it is worth noting that there is the `$` operator, that has a greater precedence than almost everything, and effectively works as if just wrapping expressions on both sides in parentheses, so
`putStrLn $ "\nFound entry: " ++ output`
becomes
`(putStrLn) ("\nFound entry: " ++ output)`
which means the same as
`putStrln ("\nFound entry: " ++ output)`

Comment: sure, probably I'll complete my answer

Comment: Left associativity of function application is not involved here. The real culprit is that function application has higher precedence than any infix operator.